# Who voted to delete an answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

If someone votes to delete an answer that I posted and I don't know why, I could ask them what part of the posting they object to and use that information to edit the posting, provided I know who they are. Is there some way to tell who they are?

Comment: Are you referring to answers that receives delete votes but is not yet deleted?

Comment: Why would the information be useful?  The only way I can think of is if you would want to gather evidence that users were targeting you with delete votes. But if that were the goal, why don't you just contact mods with your suspicions?

Comment: @rschwieb : It would be useful for the purpose of asking those who voted to delete specifically what their reason are. Then I might be able to use that to edit the answer.

Comment: @rschwieb : I have no such suspicions.

Comment: @rschwieb : I have edited the question above in view of your comment.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think my use-case is far more obvious than yours.  Trying to circumvent the built-in anonymity to confront people personally did not occur to me.  I think a good feature request would be something like "button to ask downvoters for feedback" which isn't so exposing. We've probably even had requests for such types of pinging mechanisms before,

Comment: While I'm at it, let me explain that I cast my downvote here precisely because I see no need to facilitate listing identities, and that there are more obvious ideas that would accomplish the same thing (request for feedback) that don't require the list, or as much work on the asker's part to request.

Comment: I like the idea of a mechanism that sends (one time only) a message (to recipients unknown to the user) like "really would appreciate your feedback on why you downvoted" or "please see the post again because I edited." I know we've considered them in the past but I am not knowledgeable about what was debated.

Comment: @rschwieb : Could you post that to "meta" as a feature request?

Comment: @MichaelHardy If I had time to review existing requests of the same type, and a volition to write up a new one, I would. But right now it's not my circus.

Comment: @rschwieb : I think it would be better to include the purpose: "I would appreciate your feedback on why you voted to delete so that I can edit the posting accordingly or use that information in future postings." $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sure a successful version of the request would have satisfactory versions of purpose authored in during implementation.  Good luck

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, if the answer gets deleted by enough delete votes, users with enough rep can see who cast the first two delete votes. Other than that, I believe delete votes are anonymous even to site moderators.

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE "users with enough rep can see who cast the first two delete votes" END QUOTE. How?

Comment: I looked at a recently deleted answer by @MichaelHardy and because I could see the deleted post, I could also see the banner where the votes to delete it were attributed.

Comment: @hardmath : Where would I find such a "banner"?

Comment: "users with enough rep can see who cast the first two delete votes" I do not understand the distinction that is made here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  it is in the post at the top of the post, it looks similar to  the banner that indicates that a question  is closed.

Comment: Maybe I get what is meant now. The "first" refers to a case of redeletion. But usually there are three not two users whence my confusion. (The "two" was also in the question though and this might explain it.)

Comment: Delete votes are not anonymous to site moderators.